# Does Action must have a Route in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

(I'm doing exercises from Symfony 2 book (not official). The book is running on Symfony 2.0.10, I'm running with Symfony 2.6. Maybe some differences in this context between these versions.)

The Book tells me to make project where I should **extends** template that is a View of Action by

```
   line7: {% render 'MyNovelBundle:Default:menu' %}
```

and this menuAction job is only to do some array, so no Route() need here.

But error display:

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No route found for "GET Default:menu"") in app/Resources/views/layout.html.twig at line 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 2.6 differs from 2.0. You should [embed controller's action result](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) in a bit different way

```
{{ render(controller(
    'MyNovelBundle:Default:menu'
)) }}
```